# Uncaught ReferenceError: resultCont is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to create a basic api consuming html,css & js app but getting this error in js part
Error : **Uncaught ReferenceError: resultCont is not defined**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSfPl.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>ValidateX - Email Validator For your Business</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/email.svg" alt="logo">
               <span> ValidateX</span></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="container">
        <h1>Enter Your Email to Validate</h1>
            <form action="/submit" method="post">
                <!-- Input Filed to Validate Email Address --> 
                <input placeholder="Enter your email to validate" type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
                <br><br>
                <!-- Submit button -->
                <input id="submitBtn" class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Your Results</h2>
            <div id="resultCont">
                Your results will show here
                
            </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        Copyright 2023 | ValidateX.com  | All Rights Reserved
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

JS CODE :

```
console.log("This is my script!") 

let result = {
    "tag": "",
    "free": true,
    "role": false,
    "user": "Aniket1234",
    "email": "Aniket1234@gmail.com",
    "score": 0.64,
    "state": "deliverable",
    "domain": "gmail.com",
    "reason": "valid_mailbox",
    "mx_found": true,
    "catch_all": null,
    "disposable": false,
    "smtp_check": true,
    "did_you_mean": "",
    "format_valid": true
  }

  let str =``

  for (item of Object.keys(result)){
    str = str + `<div>${item}: ${result[item]}</div>`
  }
  resultCont.innerHTML = str
```

Please guide me how I can resolve this issue.

In HTML part I have already defined resultCont as div id but still I'm facing this issue.

Comment: Hi @DiegoD, Thanks for your comment. 
It should not be a constant.
In HTML part I added nested <div>

 <div class="container">
            <h2>Your Results</h2>
            <div id="resultCont">
                Your results will show here
            </div>
and I'm tying to show the data in <div> using JS(resultCont)

Comment: `resultCont` is not a real variable in your JS code, it is a HTML ID, nothing more, you need to get a reference to the element in JS by writing: 
```document.getElementById("resultCont").innerHTML = str```